# Why does this short program never complete?

Tags: c#, .net, waithandle

Through debugging a problem of my own, I have managed to recreate a tiny program which behaves very unusually:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace CancelBug
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var unused = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var cancelled = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) => cancelled.Set();
            Console.WriteLine("Running. The only thing to do now is ctrl+c or close the window...");
            WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { unused, cancelled });
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect this program to:

- display the first line
- wait until the user tries to exit the program
- display the second line
- wait until the user presses enter
- exit

However, once this makes it past the call to `WaitHandle.WaitAny`, it seems to hang on random lines. Sometimes the last line will never be printed, sometimes it will be printed but the enter key is never read. With a larger code base, it can execute more lines of code and still hang at a seemingly random position.

Can anyone explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: Looks to me like it might be the debugger. I ran the program outside the debugger and it forces exit each time without printing any more lines.

Comment: I think Fregger's answer explains why a forced exit is the expected behaviour (who knew you had to cancel the cancel). I suppose the process isn't terminating for me because the debugger is attached

Comment: That answer is correct if you don't want to continue exiting. If you want to listen to the `Ctrl+C` then you _don't_ cancel the event. You can also disable the `Ctrl+C` special key combination on the console itself if you want to avoid users doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to cancel the `CTRL+C` command or else your process will be terminated:

```
Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    cancelled.Set();
};
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecanceleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx:

> If the Cancel property is set to true in the event handler, the
>   process is resumed; otherwise, the process is terminated. By default,
>   the value of the ConsoleCancelEventArgs property is false, and the
>   process terminates.

Comment: Oh good grief, is it really this simple? I have spent a few hours on this... I will try this tomorrow morning and let you know

Comment: I got caught up in the fact that it doesn't happen when using `cancelled.WaitOne()`, but it does happen when using `WaitHandle.WaitAny()`

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + C` is global command to close the command window. So, This key combination will close the window before the actual program ends. Try using other key.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the application without the debugger (directly from the command line).

Here's my test app that behaves as you expect, according to my test.

```
        var cancelled = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Ctrl+C detected...");
            cancelled.Set();
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Running. The only thing to do now is ctrl+c or close the window...");
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { cancelled });
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You have addressed the issue (thanks), but you haven't explained the code change you made. I think Fregger's answer deserves the credit